# creating a proxy site

Tags: proxy, youtube

Youtube is banned in turkey. So i want allow people to see youtube videos from my site.
Basically my site will act as a proxy for users to get access to youtube videos.
I also want to provide user to search youtube vidos on my site. And allow the user to play and download the videos.

I will prefed do the above thing in j2ee/jsp/php.

Can a applet be used in this situaltion. If yes how??

I want to devlop siter like video75.com which is the example of what i am trying to achieve. This site is not banned in turkey.

Comment: Clint must be paying you mega bucks to be asking this question over and over again!

Comment: I can think of one other site I'd like to see "turkey" (aka your office policy as you stated in one of the many duplicates you've deleted after they where closed) ban you from browsing....

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a perfect way to get your site banned in Turkey, as well..

To enable users from Turkey to browse the web without restrictions, I would recommend something like [TOR](http://www.torproject.org/)

I don't have experience if tor works with YouTube.

Comment: Completely agree! setting up a TOR relay takes few minutes and allows to help people circumventing censorship in Turkey as well as in many other places (i.e. Iran). If you have spare bandwidth and access to a server, I definitively believe this would serve the cause much better!

Comment: there are some sites like video75.com which is the example of what i am trying to achieve. This site is not banned in turkey.

Comment: i want to devlop a website and a p2p

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source asp.net proxy app, you can get some hints from it.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/asproxy/
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/asproxy.aspx

Jsp/php can be used with the same approach.